# NSRegularExpression's numberOfMatchesInString always returns one!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I have the following code:

```
NSString *text = @"http://bit.ly/111 http://bit.ly/222 http://www.www.www";
NSRegularExpression *aLinkRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@".*http://.*" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [aLinkRegex numberOfMatchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
```

I want to find the number of http's in the text (I know this isn't a good regex), but numberOfMatchesInString always returns 1, while it should return 3 in the above code.

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with the above code?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one match, because your regular expression matches the first `http://` and the `.*` "eats" the rest of the string.

Why not search for something more like:

```
http://
```

or if you are trying to capture each URL in full, something like:

```
http://[^ ]*
```

Which means search for anything after http:// that is not a space.

You should really look into reading through some kind of regular expression guide.

Comment: This explains a lot. I really need to read more about regular expressions. Thank you Kendall, you're the best.

Comment: Mota: Even better would be to use John Gruber's URL-matching regex (assuming it works with NSRegularExpression) http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls or Stephen Holt's AutoHyperlinks framework: https://bitbucket.org/sholt/autohyperlinks2/wiki/Home

Comment: I was going to mention that, although if he just has a series of space separated URL's a simpler approach would be a lot cheaper to parse.

Come to think of it, if that's the case he really should just use componentsSeperatedByString